# SWR mutate local state only

Tags: reactjs, swr

Is it possible to use SWR to mutate the local state only?
I've got some usecases in which:

1. I fetch some resource from an API
2. The user does operations on it (across multiple components). These operations should only be in memory.
3. User clicks "Save" button, so the updates should now be persisted remotely.

In other words, can I use `mutate` to 1) apply changes only in memory and 2) apply and persist changes remotely? In a way I'm using SWR for state-management I guess.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? You can pass data to `mutate` to update the local state. You would however need to disable revalidation for the data to make sure it's not refetched, so it's probably better to store the local/modified state separately. Trying to force the SWR hook to give you both server data and local data at different times will just be a mess.

Comment: I had a look yes, there was no obvious solution for "updated only local without making API requests". Would you instead suggest to use a combination of SWR + state management (say zustand) ?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's a better approach. I do something similar in my ows projects, but then all the editing is done within "one place/screen" of the app, so I just pass a copy of the fetched data to a form component that can then modify it and then apply (send it to the server) or discard when done. If you involve zustand or some other state manager to handle the local state you would get more freedom in how it's handled in transitions and reloads etc.

Comment: Oh, that's actually another good idea. Leave it to a form component (forms like formik/ReactHookForm can span multiple components). Thanks!